# Auditd rules exclude messages using acct field

Tags: linux

Is there a way to use the auditd filter rules to exclude log messages containing the acct field?

I can exclude some of the messages by using the auid field but unfortunately I am getting messages across multiple user accounts.  My current rule is as follows and works for just the auid=80004 which is the test user:

```
-a exclude,always -F auid=test
```

Here's a dirty sample of what I am seeing in the logs:

```
type=USER_START msg=audit(1695832501.671:9331550): pid = 22100 uid=0 auid=4294967295 subj=xxxx msg='op=pubkey_auth rport=xxxx acct="test" exe="xxxx" hostname=? addr=xxxx terminal=? res=success'
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1695832501.712.9331801): pid = 23839 uid=0 auid=80004 subj=xxxx msg='op=pubkey_auth acct="test" exe="xxxx" hostname=server1 addr=xxxx terminal=ssh res=success'
```

As you can see I have multiple user accounts reporting messages pertaining to the acct="test" and what like to filter those out, based on that field.  I realize I can filter out based on multiple auids but would prefer to use the acct= field if possible.